# Sort the dictionary after the value after the key

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

I have a problem with sorting dictionary:

```
SortedDictionary<string, List<int>> mySortedDictionary;
```

I want to create new `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` with data from mySortedDictionary, which is sorted by value(exactly by  the number of items list in other words List.Count) ascending and while the lists.Count are the same, the keys are sorted alphabetically ascending. Can anyone drop me an idea how to do this?

```
mySortedDictionary.Add("orange", List<2,9>) //List.Count = 2
mySortedDictionary.Add("money", List<2,4,8,9>)   //4
mySortedDictionary.Add("monkey", List<2,4,9>)   //3
mySortedDictionary.Add("hokey", List<2,5,9>)   //3

//result: order in new sorted Dictionary//
"orange", List<2,9>
"hokey", List<2,5,9>
"monkey", List<2,4,9>
"money", List<2,4,8,9>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Dictionary per se doesn't have any order. Even if you come up with an algorithm to insert into a dictionary in a particular order there is no guarantee you will get them back in same order.

Comment: @Partha `SortedDictionary` has an order (the `key`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SortedDictionary` stores data by sorting over `key` and this is intrinsic to it i.e. cannot be replaced by a custom sorting. So if you want a `Dictionary` like interface, you will have to build a custom Data structure.

If the reading the data in sorted order operation will happen frequently, you need to devise a mechanism to store the sorted data (cache the sorted data and original data separately) or store the data in a sorted manner. Remember that the `Value` in the dictionary might change during the life-time of the data structure, so you might have to re-order your data. This might not be a trivial exercise.

But if you  really want a `Dictionary` interface in general, but sometimes need the data to be obtained in specific sequence, then the below approach will be helpful.

Store the data in a regular `Dictionary`. To obtain the `Dictionary` data in sorted order, you can provide a method like below.

```
IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>> GetSortedData() {
    return mySortedDictionary.OrderBy(item => item.Value.Count).ThenBy(item => item.Key);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks!!! That's what I meant. Now my application works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `SortedDictionary` types only sort on the `key` part (which was part of your requirement), but you can also use the `OrderBy()` method to specify a custom ordering. Note that this does not change the order of the elements in the dictionary, instead it returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` with the specified order. So if you want to change the order, you would have to re-assign the dictionary to the result of the `OrderBy` call. If that's what you're trying to do, maybe this will help:

```
var mySortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, List<int>>
{
    {"orange", new List<int> {2, 9}},
    {"money", new List<int> {2, 4, 8, 9}},
    {"monkey", new List<int> {2, 4, 9}},
    {"hokey", new List<int> {2, 5, 9}}
};

foreach (var item in mySortedDictionary.OrderBy(item => item.Value.Count))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {string.Join(", ", item.Value)}");
}
```

Output:

[image]

To keep this order in the dictionary, you would have to do a reassignment, like so:

```
mySortedDictionary = mySortedDictionary.OrderBy(item => item.Value.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom class to implement `IComparable` so the sort is as you want to use a `SortedDictionary`.

```
public class ncKey : IComparable {
    public int count;
    public string name;

    public int CompareTo(object other) {
        var b = other as ncKey;
        var ans1 = count.CompareTo(b?.count);
        return (ans1 == 0) ? name.CompareTo(b?.name) : ans1;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the class to have a properly sorted dictionary:

```
var newSD = new SortedDictionary<ncKey, List<int>>();

foreach (var kv in origSD)
    newSD.Add(new ncKey { count = kv.Value.Count(), name = kv.Key }, kv.Value);
```

Of course, I wonder if you really wouldn't be better off with a `SortedList` and why you are using dictionaries at all.